# Defining Error of An Array with Two Index

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, indexing

I get an error such as;

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\deneme.py", line 42, in 
>       G[alpha][n]=compute_G(x,n) NameError: name 'G' is not defined

Here is my code:

```
N = 20
N_cor = 25
N_cf = 25
a = 0.5
eps = 1.4

def update(x):
    for j in range(0,N):
        old_x = x[j]
        old_Sj = S(j,x)
        x[j] = x[j] + random.uniform(-eps,eps)
        dS = S(j,x) - old_Sj
        if dS>0 and exp(-dS)<random.uniform(0,1):
            x[j] = old_x

def S(j,x):
    jp = (j+1)%N
    jm = (j-1)%N
    return a*x[j]**2/2 + x[j]*(x[j]-x[jp]-x[jm])/a

def compute_G(x,n):
    g = 0
    for j in range(0,N):
        g = g + x[j]*x[(j+n)%N]
        return g/N

#def MCaverage(x,G):
import random
from math import exp
x=[]
for j in range(0,N):
    x.append(0.0)
    print"x(%d)=%f"%(j,x[j])
for j in range(0,5*N_cor):
    update(x)
for alpha in range(0,N_cf):
    for j in range(0,N_cor):
        update(x)
        for i in range(0,N):
            print"x(%d)=%f"%(i,x[i])        
    for n in range(0,N):
        G[alpha][n]=compute_G(x,n)
for n in range(0,N):
    avg_G = 0
    for alpha in range(0,N_cf):
        avg_G = avg_G + G[alpha][n]
        avg_G = avg_G / N_cf
        print "G(%d) = %f"%(n,avg_G)
```

When i define G I get another error such as:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\deneme.py", line 43, in 
>       G[alpha][n]=compute_G(x,n) IndexError: list index out of range

Here is how i define G:

```
...
for alpha in range(0,N_cf):
    for j in range(0,N_cor):
        update(x)
    for n in range(0,N):
        G=[][]
        G[alpha][n]=compute_G(x,n)
...
```

What should i do to define an array with two index ie a two dimensional matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python `a=[]` defines a list, not an array. It certainly can be used to store a lot of elements all of the same numeric type, and one can define a mapping from two integers indexing a rectangular array to one list index. It's rather going against the grain, though. Hard to program and inefficiently stored, because lists are intended as ordered collections of objects which may be of arbitrary type.

What you probably need most is a direction to where to start reading. Here it is. Learn about Numpy [http://www.numpy.org/](http://www.numpy.org/%20Numpy), which is a Python module for use in typical scienticic calculations with arrays of (mostly) numeric data in which all the elements are of the same type. Here is a brief taster, after you have installed numpy.

```
>>> import numpy as np # importing as np is conventional
>>> p = np.zeros( (6,4) )  # two dimensional, 24 elements in total
>>> for i in range(4): p[i,i]=1
>>> p
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

numpy arrays are efficient ways of manipulating as much data as you can fit into your computer's RAM.

Underlying numpy is Python's array.array datatype, but it is rarely used on its own. numpy is the support code that you'll usually not want to write for yourself. Not least, because when your arrays are millions or billions of elements, you can't afford the inefficiency of inner loops over their indices in an interpreted language like Python. Numpy offers you row-, column- and array-level operations whose underlying code is compiled and optimized, so it runs considerably faster.

Comment: I have tried to import numpy. But i get an error such as, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\deneme.py", line 30, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>>

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Python on Windows. On Linux you need to use your system's installer or pip to add numpy to a vanilla Python install. Maybe Google for "install numpy on windows <version>" and if that fails you, ask here?